# What is the difference between the V-OFDM and OSDM

Tags: fft, digital-communications, ofdm

I am trying to understand the difference(s) between V-OFDM (Vector Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing) and OSDM (Orthogonal Signal Division Multiplexing) which are used as a multicarrier modulation techniques in wireless communication. Based on what I understand both are dividing the sub-carriers into  groups of sub-carriers vertically, and then process the $DFT$ horizontally. But when checking online and read different papers and books, some are talking about V-OFDM and others OSDM !!

Could anyone please explain further about differences between them ? design and differences  of OSDM from V-OFDM? Or they are similar, only two different names with same technology !!!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are little bit different in performing the $DFT$ and the adding of $CP$. her you can read more details about those differences : https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/ICC.2009.5198846

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the performance, one only needs to check the receive equations before demodulation/decoding: $y=hx+w$, where $x$ is the signal to demodulate/decode (maybe vector), $h$ is the channel (maybe in frequency domain, and maybe in matrix form), $y$ is the available data (maybe vector), $w$ is the AWGN (maybe vector). If they are the same, then their performances are the same and I would say the systems are the same.